# SQL Server COUNT() seems to be ignoring WHERE

Tags: sql-server, count, where

I am trying to set up a SQL Server query that lists the count of people signed up for tours during a conference event and then displays the total sum. This is my SQL code that is coming close, but it is ignoring the WHERE clause for the grand total (but not the individual totals):

```
SELECT     SiteTour, COUNT(SiteTour) AS count
FROM       tblConference
WHERE      (RegistrationType NOT LIKE 'cancellation')
GROUP BY   SiteTour
UNION ALL
SELECT     'TOTAL' AS SiteTour, COUNT(SiteTour) AS Expr1
FROM       tblConference AS tblConference_1
```

Here is what it is producing:

```
         0
Tour1   22
Tour2   30
Tour3   30
----------
TOTAL   83
```

(Tour1 count of 22 is correct, because there is one RegistrationType cancellation. However, the TOTAL of 83 should be 82.)

Also, I am getting an initial row, I guess based on counting NULLs, that shows a 0. Is there some way prevent this?

Please help me correct this. Thank you.

Comment: instead of doing `LIKE`, you should do `=` since you are not searching for wildcard `%cancellation%`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the same where clause in your union select.

```
SELECT     SiteTour, COUNT(SiteTour) AS count
FROM       tblConference
WHERE      (RegistrationType NOT LIKE 'cancellation')
GROUP BY   SiteTour
UNION ALL
SELECT     'TOTAL' AS SiteTour, COUNT(tblConference_1.SiteTour) AS Expr1
FROM       tblConference AS tblConference_1
WHERE      (tblConference_1.RegistrationType NOT LIKE 'cancellation')
```

Comment: Face palm. Thanks, that is it! Is there some way to get rid of the initial 0 row?

Comment: @JDuke - After the `GROUP BY`, try `HAVING COUNT(SiteTour) > 0`

Comment: How can you get a row with a zero count? That can only happen with an outer join, not a query of a single table.

Comment: @Barmar - COUNT(myColumn) will only count non-null values.  COUNT(*) will count the presence of a row.

Answer (score 5):

You should avoid doing the `COUNT` twice.

```
;WITH Counts AS
(
    SELECT     SiteTour, COUNT(SiteTour) AS count
    FROM       tblConference
    WHERE      RegistrationType <> 'cancellation' AND SiteTour IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY   SiteTour
),
Totals AS
(
    SELECT
        C.SiteTour,
        C.count
    FROM
        Counts AS C
    UNION ALL
    SELECT     
        'TOTAL' AS SiteTour, 
        SUM(C.count) AS count
    FROM
        Counts AS C
)
SELECT
    T.SiteTour,
    T.Count
FROM
    Totals AS T
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN T.SiteTour <> 'TOTAL' THEN 1
        ELSE 2 END,
    T.SiteTour
```

This way all your filters are written only once too.

Comment: While I agree that this is cleaner code, be aware that SQL won't reuse the result from Counts, it will get the data from the table twice.

Comment: @AlwaysLoadingData Actually, that depends on what the optimizer decides based on it's statistical knowledge of the tables.  AFAIK, it is possible that it could decide to spool the intermediate results and then reuse them.

Comment: (well, maybe, not sure about this query)

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the query has a Where condition

```
SELECT     SiteTour, COUNT(SiteTour) AS count
FROM       tblConference
WHERE      (RegistrationType NOT LIKE 'cancellation')
GROUP BY   SiteTour
```

the second part has none

```
SELECT     'TOTAL' AS SiteTour, COUNT(SiteTour) AS Expr1
FROM       tblConference AS tblConference_1
```

So it's not ignoring the where. Simply, there is no where.